# CRTP with reinterpret_cast into target class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, crtp

### Background

I'd like facades to be applied on ad-hoc basis, and not baking them into the class itself. But I need to operate on the data, so I need `this` to be accessible from the facade. Here is a small example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct x_getter
{
    friend T;

    double x() const
    {
        return (*real_self)[0];
    }

    void x(double new_x)
    {
        (*real_self)[0] = new_x;
    }

private:
    T* real_self = reinterpret_cast<T*>(this);
    x_getter() = default; //prevents accidental creation
};

struct coordinates : std::array<double, 3>, x_getter<coordinates>
{
    using std::array<double, 3>::array;
};


int main()
{
    coordinates origin{};
    std::cout << origin.x();
    origin.x(12.7);
    std::cout << ' ' << origin.x() << '\n';
}
```

[It segfaults](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aPEvV1KjdoMInbdo). Using something similar a while back, I got unlucky to be able to get away with it.

### Question

How do I make `this` with type of target class be available in facade class?

### My understanding of class layout

Somewhere inside of the object, in unordered manner, there are array and `x_getter`. By `reinterpret_cast`ing it, I'm trying to trick it to think that `this` is `coordinates`, but when it performs `operator[]`, the offset which is used is a bit off, which goes outside of the object, thus segfaulting.

Comment: To get to derived class you should use `static_cast` inside of the method.

Comment: @VTT, could you please post an answer with the method in it, and may be some links for me to read up. Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `reinterpret_cast` does not work because `this` pointer does not point at the beginning of `coordinates` class since it inherits from `array` before inheriting from `x_getter`. The memory layout for this class looks like this:

```
coordinates
|- std::array<double, 3>
|- x_getter
```

When you use `reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)` the address stored in `this` pointer is the address of `x_getter` object, but you force compiler to assume that it is actually an address of `coordinates` object. So dereferencing such a pointer to derived class leads to all kinds of undefined behavior.

Typically CRTP should use `static_cast` inside of method:

```
double x() const
{
    return (*static_cast<TDerived const *>(this))[0];
}
```

Unlike `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast` will properly adjust `this` pointer to correctly point at derived object.

Comment: Oh, so the inheritance order affects the layout? I thought that the layout will be unordered relative to inheritance order.

Comment: @Incomputable Using `reinterpret_cast` here would be still wrong even if there was no `array` class inherited.

Comment: I believe I got why it is terribly wrong. It is like not shifting the base pointer to the right place, but leaving it where it is. Thanks, now my understanding doesn’t have holes.

Comment: @Incomputable It is `static_cast` that properly shifts pointer. `reinterpret_cast<T*>` is a direct order to assume that whatever is stored in argument is already a valid pointer to `T`.

Comment: is std::launder a safe reinterpret_cast then?

Comment: @Incomputable Not really, it would fail here the same way `reinterpret_cast` did. Actually the purpose of `std::launder` is to deal with fancy aliasing.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all of the knowledge.